# Python: How to accept an object (bid) from a list of objects (bids) posted by several users and returns the user details using django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have created a Django project in which a user can bid with certain amount on a particular item. I have also make a template for the item's owner so that he can see the list of the bidders their amount and rank. In order to accept a bid, i make a Accept field in the list.

Here is my bidder's list page.

[image: Bidder List] When the item owner likes a bid amount, he can accept it and he will be redirect to that particular bidder details.

How can i make a django model, so that the accepted bid will be stored and return the bidder details.

here's my code for bid_create and bid_list:

models.py :

```
class Bid(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
```

forms.py:

```
class BidForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Bid
    fields = ["amount"]
```

views.py :

```
@login_required     
def bid_create(request):
    form = BidForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        print(form.cleaned_data.get("amount"))
        instance.user = request.user
        instance.save()

    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, "bid.html", context)

def bid_list(request):
    queryset = Bid.objects.all().order_by('amount')

    current_rank = 1
    counter = 0

    for bid in queryset:
        if counter < 1: # for first bid
            bid.rank = current_rank
        else: # for other bids
            if bid.amount == queryset[counter - 1].amount:
            # if bid and previous bid have same score,
            # give them the same rank
                bid.rank = current_rank
            else:
            # first update the rank
                current_rank += 1
            # then assign new rank to bid
                bid.rank = current_rank
        counter += 1

    context = {"bid_rank" : "current_rank",
               "queryset": queryset, 
               "title": "List"}

    return render(request, 'bid_list.html', context)
```

Comment: Can you please give me source code of project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is very general, so I will just suggest a couple of things.

If you want to store this information I would create a third class (`Auction`?) which has, at least, an owner. And then in the `Bid` i would add a ForeignKey to that Auction.

```
class Auction(models.Model):
    owner = ...
    accepted_bid = models.ForeignKey(Bid)
```

Then you need to create a view (accept_bid), and an URl pointing at it, which receives an `auction_id` and a `bid_id`. The view will store this accepted bid in the Auction, and redirect to wherever you need.

Comment: class Auction(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    accepted_bid = models.ForeignKey(Bid)

views.py:
def accept_bid(request):
 return render(request, 'accept_bid.html')

how can i pass the accepted_bid in the Auction to my views?

Comment: You need to create an URL pointing to the view, so you can call it from the template with the `bid_id`. Have a look at [this example](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/models_templates.html#parameterised-url-mapping) where the last url is passing a parameter to the `category` view. (Completing this tutorial would help you a lot)